# COM interop with named indexer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com, interop, indexer

I am trying to use a named indexer in a COM library from c# in Visual Studio 2012.

The signature is:

```
public virtual dynamic this[ref BTCALL_Ver12.StkGroupT_Fields New_Field, [ref short ArrPos1 = 0], [ref short ArrPos2 = 0]] { set; get; }
Member of BTCALL_Ver12.StkGroupTClass
```

When I use this syntax:

```
BTCALL_Ver12.StkGroupT sg = new BTCALL_Ver12.StkGroupT();

dynamic y = sg[BTCALL_Ver12.StkGroupT_Fields.SGDesc];
```

I get an error message something like:

> Error 1   Property, indexer, or event 'BTCALL_Ver12._StkGroupT.this[ref BTCALL_Ver12.StkGroupT_Fields, ref short, ref short]' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'BTCALL_Ver12._StkGroupT.get_Field(ref BTCALL_Ver12.StkGroupT_Fields, ref short, ref short)' or 'BTCALL_Ver12._StkGroupT.set_Field(ref BTCALL_Ver12.StkGroupT_Fields, ref short, ref short, ref object)'    C:\Users\Alex\dev\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Form1.cs    49  25  PastelSDK

I have tried to use the format get_this() as suggested by the error message without success. Any ideas?

Comment: It recommends you use get_Field(), why are you trying get_this()??

Comment: Because I am an idiot! Thank you very much. FWIW I saw this in John Skeets book: SynonymInfo SynonymInfo[string Word,
ref object LanguageId = Type.Missing] and then app.get_SynonymInfo("painful", ref missing) so I assumed "Field" was a place holder like "SynonymInfo". So there is still something I am not getting but I'll do some reading.

Comment: Sorry, that is Jon Skeet of course.